# How to read Group permissions and write it to an Excel in AEM

Tags: aem

We have a requirement in which we have to read all the permissions given to a group and write it to an excel. I want to know how to read the group permission programmaticaly. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tushar

Answer (score 2):

### AEM 6.0+ (Apache OAK)

The permissioning scheme is replicated in the separated branch under `/jcr:system/rep:permissionStore`. A node for each authorizable (user/group) is available under `/jcr:system/rep:permissionStore/crx.default/$authId`. You can simply iterate over all permissions then using e.g. [AEM Groovy Console](https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console) or through JCR/Sling API.

```
def crawlAcls(authId) {
    getResource("/jcr:system/rep:permissionStore/crx.default/$authId").getChildren().each{ r ->
        def path = r.valueMap["rep:accessControlledPath"]
        doTheStuff(authId, path)
}
```

}

### AEM 5.6 and previous

Use search query. You should be looking for nodes of `rep:ACL` type. The basic query (which is highly ineffective!) but may be a starting point for further improvements is as following:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM [rep:ACL] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('" + rootPath + "')";
Iterator<Resource> resouces = resourceResolver.findResources(queryString, Query.JCR_SQL2);

while (resultNodes.hasNext()) {
    Resource resource = resouces.next();
    checkAndDoTheStuff(resource.getPath(), authorizable, acm)
}

private void checkAndDoTheStuff(String path, Authorizable authorizable, AccessControlManager acm) throws RepositoryException {
    Principal principal = authorizable.getPrincipal();
    JackrabbitAccessControlList jackrabbitAcl = JackrabbitAccessControlListUtil.getModifiableAcl(acm, path);
    AccessControlEntry[] accessControlEntries = jackrabbitAcl.getAccessControlEntries();

    for (AccessControlEntry accessControlEntry : accessControlEntries) {
        if (accessControlEntry.getPrincipal().equals(principal)) {
            doTheStuff(authorizable, path)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I want to know is how to access this by sling api. Could you please share any code snippet for that

Comment: @Tushar the permissions are applied directly on the repository level (OAK). Sling is about Sling Authenticator only but this is not the layer you are looking for. You should fall back to the JCR API instead.

Comment: could you please give any code snippet for the same